# .Net Reactive Observable issue: when use FromEvent() method, get an exception trying to dispose subscription

Tags: c#, .net, observable, reactive-programming, synchronizationcontext

I use Reactive .Net Observable FromEvent() method:

```
 var someObservable = Observable.FromEvent<T>(dc => dataView.DataChanged += dc, dc =>  dataView.DataChanged -= dc)
 .Publish().Refcount();


 var subscription = someObservable.Subscribe(someHandler);
```

Subscription happens successfully. If I call subscription.Dispose() in the same method (in the same thread with the same syncronization context),
it's disposed successfully.

But actually I need to dispose it later. We use SignalR hubs. If I save subscription to dispose it later and then try to call

```
subscription.Dispose();
```

in another thread, I get an exception:
InvalidOperationException: `"An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle. If this exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure that the Page is marked <%@ Page Async="true".`

As per documentation, FromEvent() captures SynchronizationContext to call addHandler and removeHandler later on it. Actually for us execution of add and remove handlers in the initial context is not important but I didn't find possibility to prevent syncronizationcontext capturing by FromEvent() method.

But if I make a hack and do something like

```
await(Task.Run(() =>

        {
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(context);

            subscription.Dispose();

        }));
```

where context is that synchronization context where FromEvent() was called then it works fine and exception doesn't occur.

Could you please clarify what really happens, why running on previous context works fine but fails without it?

I've tried to call SubscribeOn() method and set SynchronizationContext.Current (actually it should happen inside from event). Tried to create own scheduler and pass it to SubscribeOn or to FromEvent(addHandler, removeHandler, scheduler). Always the same exception.

Tried to set in web.config

```
add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"
```

So subscription disposing works only if I am calling

```
subscription.Dispose();
```

on the saved synchronizationcontext, but it's not clear and looks like a hack.

There are no async void operations in my code. Methods where subscription is created and where it's destroyed are called from methods called inside SignalR Hub methods:

```
public async Task<OperationResult> Start()

{

// some code here

   await service.Start(); // service.Start() handles subscription creation
}


public async Task<OperationResult> Delete()

{

    await service.Delete(); // service.Delete() handles subscription disposing

}
```